# Making tqdm and the like functions accept different types of parameters in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, tqdm

This is not specific to tqdm but a generic question about passing parameters to a function in Python. I want to achieve the following functionality without having to make copies of the entire-block under tqdm. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
if flag == True:
    with tqdm(dataloader, total=args.num_train_batches) as pbar:
else:
    with tqdm(dataloader) as pbar:
```

More specifically, can I pass parameters in a way like this?

```
if flag == True:
    tqdm_args = dataloader, total=args.num_train_batches
else:
    tqdm_args = dataloader
with tqdm(tqdm_args) as pbar:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually fairly simple to do, as it seems they thought of this when making Python. You can use Python's [ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) to do this, condensing what you have above to a single line:

```
with tqdm(dataloader, total=args.num_train_batches if flag else None) as pbar:
  # ...
```

**Edit:** to answer with your preferred method you mentioned, yes. That's also possible. If you put those arguments into a list (or dictionary, if you have keyword args) and then put a `*` (or `**` for a dictionary) in front of the list's name when calling the function, it unpacks the list into a set of arguments.

Example using a list:

```
if flag: # if flag is a boolean, putting "== True" does nothing
    tqdm_args = [dataloader, None, args.num_train_batches]
else:
    tqdm_args = [dataloader]
with tqdm(*tqdm_args) as pbar:
    # ...
```

Example with a dictionary:

```
if flag:
  tqdm_kwargs = {"iterable": dataloader, "total": args.num_train_batches}
else:
  tqdm_kwargs = {"iterable": dataloader}
with tqdm(**tqdm_kwargs) as pbar:
  # ...
```

Happy to be of assistance!

Comment: The first one works, but the second throws error at total=args.num_train_batches

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. I'll remedy that. It happens because keyword args are different than regular args—they need to be passed using a dict.

Comment: @kkgarg Okay, I fixed it. Each block of code should work now. They each have their own best use cases imo, but I tend to use the ternary operator the most often myself.